# Trigger XMPP message from SQL Server trigger or ON INSERT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, insert, xmpp

I need to be able to send an XMPP message when a row gets inserted into a particular table in our SQL Server database (and have it not make the insert fail if the XMPP server or code isn't available/fails/etc).

Is this possible without causing the insert to fail in some circumstances?

Comment: PS - I'd be happy to use SIP or Skype or any other messaging protocol/client that runs on an IOS/Android phone/tablet.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid potentially blocking your database application, I'd recommend **NOT** to send any external messages directly from a trigger. After all, the trigger executes *in the context of the SQL statement* that caused it to fire, and if the trigger is delayed, then your statement will have to wait until the trigger is done (or has timed out).

Instead, what I'd do is this:

- insert a row into a "command" table with enough information to be able to later send your XMPP message - this can be done in the trigger
- have a **separate** piece of code, e.g. a scheduled SQL Server job, that checks that "Command" table every x minutes or hours or however frequently (or infrequently) that you need - and this job running separately and independently from your application should them attempt to send out those messages, and handle any potential error situations - while your main application happily works along not bothered by any delays, time outs etc.